# Finding the Maximum and Minimum value in python using loops

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.3

I have an assignment where I let the user input as many scores and then I have to calculate the minimum and maximum value along with how many people got those scores using for-loop. I've calculated the average and the standard deviation:

elif user_option == 3:

```
    total = 0
    for val in scores_list:
        total = total + val
    average = total/ len(scores_list)
    print (average)
elif user_option == 2:
    total = 0
    for val in scores_list:
        total = total + val
    average = total/ len(scores_list)
    diffsquared = 0
    sum_diffsquared = 0
    for val in scores_list:
        diffsquared= (val - average)**2
        sum_diffsquared= diffsquared + sum_diffsquared
    stdev= sqrt((sum_diffsquared)/len(scores_list))
    print(stdev)
```

Any ideas how to find the min and max values?

Comment: Some reformatting is in order :/. Also give a *short, standalone and runnable* sample.

Comment: Also, spaces are preferred over tabs in python

Comment: Is there a first part to your `if` statement?  Because you can't start with `elif`...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
min_val = float("inf")
max_val = -float("inf")
count_min = 0
count_max = 0

for val in scores_list:
    if val < min_val:
        min_val = val
        count_min = 1
    elif val == min_val:
        count_min += 1

    if val > max_val:
        max_val = val
        count_max = 1
    elif val == max_val:
        count_max += 1

print "Minimum score:", min_val
print "Maximum score:", max_val
print "Number of students with minimum score:", count_min
print "Number of students with maximum score:", count_max
```

EDIT: As @GL770 has noted in the comments, sys.maxint is only available in Python 2.x. In Python 2.x you could have done something like this.:

```
import sys
min_val = sys.maxint
max_val = -sys.maxint - 1
```

The `float("inf")` thing also works in Python 2.x though so this method is not required.

Comment: @GL770 Thanks for letting me know. I made it `float("inf")` and `-float("inf")` instead. That should be Python 3 compatible.

Comment: I don't think your count_min, count_max values are correct.  Think about:

     scores = [6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1]

Comment: @bcollins yeah theres a reason because in your code the count_min never gets reset to 1 if it finds a new minimum value. Also try running my code with that list. It works. For me it printed: `Minimum score: 1
Maximum score: 9
Number of students with minimum score: 3
Number of students with maximum score: 1`

Comment: Well in your *edited* list it prints: `Minimum score: 1 Maximum score: 9 Number of students with minimum score: 2 Number of students with maximum score: 1` which is correct. I don't believe there are any issues with my code in terms of correctness.

Answer (score 0):

How about the built-in functions min() and max():

```
scores_min = min(scores_list)
scores_max = max(scores_list)
```

also don't forget about numpy:

```
import numpy
scores_array = numpy.array(scores_list)
scores_mean = numpy.mean(scores_array)
scores_std = numpy.std(scores_array)
scores_min = numpy.min(scores_array)
scores_max = numpy.max(scores_array)
```

Comment: I can't use the built in functions. I have to use loops

Comment: I'm fairly certain he's not allowed to use built-ins or numpy.

Comment: ahh ok sorry.  This is just an academic exercise.